# How to Set UITabBar background image change?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can i sort the array based on distance from current location and show in tableview .when i use sorting am not getting any proper results ,am getting the array with random distance.can any one guide me for solve this issue

Comment: You have array of distance from what coordinates? Or you have array of coordinates? need more info.

Comment: your question is highly confusing. Please elaborate more on your issue and some ocde and fix the title.

Comment: Whats the relationship between title and question description?

Comment: Can you provide more details as in code?

Answer (score 0):

To sort locations based on distance from current location in best possible way would be have location points in form of struct

```
struct LocationPoints {
    var latitude: CLLocationDegrees
    var longitude: CLLocationDegrees

    func distance(to currentLocation: CLLocation) -> CLLocationDistance {
        return CLLocation(latitude: self.latitude, longitude: self.longitude).distance(from: currentLocation)
    }
}
```

Let suppose you have an array of LocationPoints having latitude & longitude

```
var coordinates: [LocationPoints] = []
            coordinates.append(LocationPoints(latitude: Double(25), longitude: Double(24)))
                coordinates.append( LocationPoints(latitude: Double(23), longitude: Double(22)))
```

sort function

```
    coordinates = sortLocationsWithCurrentLocation(locations: coordinates, currentLocation: CLLocation(latitude: Double(20), longitude: Double(21)))




    func sortLocationsWithCurrentLocation(locations:[LocationPoints],currentLocation:CLLocation) -> [LocationPoints] {
//set here current position as current location
            let currentPosition : CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 30, longitude: 24)
            let sortedLocations = locations.sorted(by: { (point1 : LocationPoints, point2 :LocationPoints) -> Bool in
                if point1.distance(to: currentPosition) < point2.distance(to: currentPosition)
                {
                    return true
                }
               return false
            })
            return sortedLocations
        }
```